# Content moves alone - HTML

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Can someone explain me why when I toggle the tabs, the content is not aligned horizontally on both tabs?

If you notice, the content table moves to the left when you go to the document.

I can't figure it out why this is happening. Any help?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="content">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <!-- ngIf: !vm.selectedTicket.customerName1 && !vm.selectedTicket.customerName2 -->
    <!-- ngIf: vm.selectedTicket.customerName1 && vm.selectedTicket.customerName2 -->
    <li ng-if="vm.selectedTicket.customerName1 &amp;&amp; vm.selectedTicket.customerName2" class="ng-scope" style=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#customer1Content" class="ng-binding" aria-expanded="false"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>&nbsp;Customer 1 Information</a></li>

    <!-- end ngIf: vm.selectedTicket.customerName1 && vm.selectedTicket.customerName2 -->
    <li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#documentContent" class="ng-binding" aria-expanded="false"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i>&nbsp;Document Information</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content top5">
    <!-- ngIf: !vm.selectedTicket.customerName1 && !vm.selectedTicket.customerName2 && vm.selectedTicket.customerName -->
    <!-- ngIf: vm.selectedTicket.customerName1 && vm.selectedTicket.customerName2 -->
    <div ng-if="vm.selectedTicket.customerName1 &amp;&amp; vm.selectedTicket.customerName2" id="customer1Content" class="tab-pane fade ng-scope" style="">
      <table class="table ipp-simple-table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th class="first-no-border ng-binding">Customer Number</th>
            <td class="first-no-border ng-binding">333</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="ng-binding">Customer Name</th>
            <td class="ng-binding">Name1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="ng-binding">Birth Date</th>
            <td class="ng-binding">08.12.2017</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="ng-binding">Account Number</th>
            <td class="ng-binding">123</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="ng-binding">Status</th>
            <td>
              <!-- ngIf: vm.selectedTicket.status.description == 'New' --><span ng-if="vm.selectedTicket.status.description == 'New'" class="ipp-color ng-scope"><b class="ng-binding">New</b></span>
              <!-- end ngIf: vm.selectedTicket.status.description == 'New' -->
              <!-- ngIf: vm.selectedTicket.status.description == 'Closed' -->
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th class="ng-binding">Target Ticket
            </th>
            <td>
              <select ng-options="ticket.docid for ticket in vm.tickets" ng-model="vm.selectedTicket" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
                <option label="1" value="object:49">1</option>
                <option label="2" value="object:50">2</option>
                <option label="3" value="object:51">3</option>
                <option label="4" value="object:52">4</option>
                <option label="5" value="object:53">5</option>
                <option label="6" value="object:54" selected="selected">6</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </div>
    <!-- end ngIf: vm.selectedTicket.customerName1 && vm.selectedTicket.customerName2 -->
    
    <div id="documentContent" class="tab-pane fade">
      <table class="table ipp-simple-table">
        <thead>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th class="first-no-border ng-binding">Document ID</th>
            <td class="first-no-border ng-binding">6</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="ng-binding">Document Date</th>
            <td class="ng-binding">05.12.2018</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="ng-binding">Document Type</th>
            <td class="ng-binding">9999</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="ng-binding">Description</th>
            <td class="w-50 ng-binding">Unkategorisiert</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th class="ng-binding">Target Ticket</th>
            <td>
              <select ng-options="ticket.docid for ticket in vm.tickets" ng-model="vm.selectedTicket" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
                <option label="1" value="object:49">1</option>
                <option label="2" value="object:50">2</option>
                <option label="3" value="object:51">3</option>
                <option label="4" value="object:52">4</option>
                <option label="5" value="object:53">5</option>
                <option label="6" value="object:54" selected="selected">6</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Because you haven't specified column widths?, You may not have noticed but the document tab has longer text in the right column, and shorter in the left, the columns are automatically scaling differently.

Comment: @NickA I just want a responsive table. Why do I need to specify widths?

Comment: Any help please??

Comment: You could give the columns a % width to keep it responsive.